# Python - Rolling Function (Step - Pandas 1.5.0)

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I updated all the relevant libraries to the latest version, hence I thought that I could now use the new feature (step) in the rolling-function:

```
print(df['600028.SS'].rolling(window=125, step=20).corr(df['600121.SS']))
```

However, when executing the command, I always get the following error message:

```
NotImplementedError: step not implemented for corr
```

How can I implement the step-feature for `corr`, or is there any way to circumvent the error message. By the way '600028.SS' and '600121.SS' are just the names of two columns in the `dataframe`

I want to get the correlation coefficient for those two stocks on a rolling basis. Every correlation coefficient should include the last 125 observations, and the step-size should be 20. And with the new step feature since the latest pandas update (1.5.0) I thought it should be fine to use now, however, I still receive the massage that step would not be implemented for `corr`.

Answer (score 0):

The symptom is easily reproduced in pandas 1.5.1, 2.0.3, and 2.1.4:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':         np.array(range(100)),
                       'b': 1 + 2 * np.array(range(100))})
>>>
>>> df.a.rolling(window=3, step=20).corr(df.b[::20])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 2852, in corr
    return super().corr(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py", line 1800, in corr
    raise NotImplementedError("step not implemented for corr")
NotImplementedError: step not implemented for corr
```

I am reading the 1.5.1 documentation, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.corr.html .
It lists four possible args:

- other
- pairwise
- ddof
- numeric_only

It doesn't mention support for `step`.
It explains that additional args
are accepted
"for NumPy compatibility and will not have an effect on the result."

The documentation for
[.rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas.DataFrame.rolling)
explains that it added support for `step` in 1.5.0,
which can produce an output shape different from the input.

The diagnostic error message is accurate.
You are attempting to use something that
is not implemented.
That won't work.

You wanted to do this:

```py
>>> df.a[::20].rolling(window=3).corr(df.b[::20])
0     NaN
20    NaN
40    1.0
60    1.0
80    1.0
dtype: float64
```

This is based on reading the documentation for the `step` argument:

> step
>
> int, default None
>
> Evaluate the window at every step result,
> equivalent to slicing as [::step].

You may want to adjust step, based on window size.